# Do I need to rebuild a courthouse if I re-conquer a city I have captured in the past?

Tags: civilization-5

If I remember correctly, courthouses are always destroyed when a city is conquered. On the other hand, when a civ loses one of their cities and then conquers it again, it does not have to build a courthouse there.

My question is, does a city become "mine" after building a courthouse, e.g. if I lose and then re-conquer it, will I have to build a courthouse again? Or do all cities remember only the original civ that built them, and only that civ doesn't need a courthouse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All cities remember only the original civ that built them. It's much more cost-efficient in the long run to raze cities and resettle in the same place with your own settler given the oftentime nigh untenable cost of the courthouse building (and the fact that it can't be purchased).

Comment: Never thought about razing and resettling. I guess this even has more impact considering that conquering a city halves the population and destroys most buildings.

Comment: Unless the city has a wonder, then you probably don't want to raze it.

Comment: The big difference is that puppeted cities don't raise your social policy costs, and they maintain their existing cultural borders.  If you raze the city and build a new one, not only do you suffer a diplomatic penalty, but other people might snatch up those nice resources before you're able to reclaim them.

Comment: @Bwarner -- usually you're at war with those people anyway.

Comment: I did have a case were one of my cities was captured by the enemy and when I reclaimed it a number of turns later I *did* have to build a Courthouse. Is there any limit how long your citizens will remember you?

Comment: @deceze what you say indicates a city *can* forget the original builder civ, so it kind of contradicts this answer. Are you positive you were the original builder?

Comment: @Oak Now that you mention it, it may be that I received that city as part of a peace treaty very early on. Pardon my bad memory, please disregard the evidence for now. I'll try to confirm if I can.