# Is a courthouse mandatory to quell occupational unhappiness?

Tags: civilization-5

If you don't build the courthouse does the city perpetually generate extra unhappiness due to the occupation, or do they eventually settle down without one?  How longer does that take with/without?

I don't know where I got the idea that if you wait long enough they'll come around... perhaps I've carried that idea over from a previous civ version? and it is no longer the case?

Comment: It probably wouldn't hurt to go through your questions and mark them as answered but that may be my inner OCD talking...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until you build a courthouse, the city will always be "occupied" and generate unhappiness.  Once built, the city will be like any other that you would have settled yourself with respect to the (un)happiness it contributes.

It seems to have the effect of putting a soft cap on how many cities you can annex at a time (to avoid going into negative happiness and severely stalling growth), as it is either fairly pricey, or it will take a few dozen turns to build.  You can finish it in 2 turns with a Great Engineer's "Hurry Production", however.

Comment: "Once built, the city will be like any other that you have settled yourself" - well, almost; apparently [cities remember who the original settlers were](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10623/do-i-need-to-rebuild-a-courthouse-if-i-re-conquer-a-city-i-have-captured-in-the-p), for purpose of re-conquering them.

Comment: 'like any other' excepting for the extra 4 coins maintenance on the courthouse?

Comment: I was probably a little too broad and just referring to the unhappiness it contributes.  There are indeed still some other differences.

Comment: Great Engineer for Course House? Lol, I never spend GP for a normal building. I prefer spending 450G for it instead.

Comment: @WN it was a different matter before they were purchasable

Answer (score 0):

An occupied city without a courthouse will always generate extra unhappiness compared to a city you founded yourself. The only way to get rid of this extra unhappiness is with a courthouse.

In addition, there used to be a bug where the courthouse would also remove the three base unhappiness in the city making annxed+courthouse cities *better* than ones you founded yourself. I'm not quite certain if this bug still exists.